# Is Numpy vectorization using C loops?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I've been reading a few articles/posts regarding `numpy`, and was wondering how vectorization in `numpy` actually works. Some articles mention the use of C loops, while others talk about things closer to the hardware such as vector instruction sets. For example, if I have the following code:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([2,4,6])
M = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

and I call the following functions:

```
c = np.dot(a,b)
M2 = M@M
test_condition = np.where(a > 2, a + 999, a)
```

Then I had assumed that the vectorized function calls in the above examples were simply a fancy way of saying that `numpy` calls a fast compiled C for loop to process each element. Is this the case, or is there something much more complicated that is actually going on under the hood?

Comment: C `for` loops can compile to hardware vectorized instructions... Definitely uses [at least a few inline asm and/or intrinsic instructions](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/search?q=asm&unscoped_q=asm) directly too.

Comment: In the context of `numpy`, `vectorization` just means using the compiled functionality.  That is mostly written in C.  Depending on the compiler and hardware there might be some specialized operations, but the basic distribution doesn't do it.  Some code uses numeric libraries (BLAS, ATLAS) if they are installed.

Comment: @hpaulj would BLAS and ATLAS use C for loops? I guess the core of my problem lies in that I thought loops were the only way one could traverse an array.

Comment: Yes, it is loops, all the way down.  But they are mostly hidden from us Python level users.  For the most part we use `numpy` as though the calculation was being done in-parallel, on all elements at once.